# How do I get '\\\\host\\printer' out of a string var of '\\host\printer' in python 2.7.5?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I get '\\\\host\\printer' out of a string var of '\\host\printer' in python 2.7.5?

My program takes in a string argument, **"\\host\printer"**, and I need to convert it to **"\\\\host\\printer"** in order to submit it as a JSON doc to a web endpoint.

Seems simple enough, but python won't let me. Here's what happens:

```
>>> data = '\\host\printer'
>>> print data.replace('\\','\\\\')
\\host\\printer
```

Now, if this **data** var was assigned a raw string, it'd work fine:

```
>>> data = r'\\host\printer'
>>> print data.replace('\\','\\\\')
\\\\host\\printer
```

However, since **data** is an input argument, I can't make it a raw string. I've tried several tricks found on SO to convert it to a raw string, but no luck with the final result, as shown below.

encode() doesn't help:

```
>>> data = '\\host\printer'    
>>> data = data.encode('string-escape')
>>> print data.replace('\\','\\\\')
\\\\host\\\\printer
```

nor does repr():

```
>>> data = '\\host\printer'
>>> data = repr(data)
>>> print data.replace('\\','\\\\')
'\\\\host\\\\printer'
```

nor does re.escape():

```
>>> import re
>>> data = '\\host\printer'
>>> data = re.escape(data)
>>> print data.replace('\\','\\\\')
\\\\host\\\\printer
```

Comment: Try printing `data`: it is not what you think it is.

Comment: @tfb yes, I have tried printing it and it certainly does not print the exact value unless I passed in a raw string. What can I do about it?

Comment: As you said, you should get the string as a raw string. Can you post more code on how you handle data as input argument ? data = raw_input('?') wouldn't do the trick ?

Comment: @alex, the string is passed in programmatically by another process. Raw_input() would only work with keyboard input, right?

Comment: @Zoomzoom yes, this is correct. When I do on python interpreter:
```>>> data = '\\host\printer'
>>> data // I get '\host\printer'```
So, from here the only solution I see is to modify the code inside the other process that send you the string because you already receive a string which is already formatted right ? Can you post the code of the process which send you the string ?

Comment: It's easy to modify the other process to pass in the string that would work, but I was hoping to avoid doing that, since I don't really have ownership of that piece. This is disappointing... Python just became a bit less attractive to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you write this:

```
>>> data = '\\host\printer'
```

You end up with `data` containing the literal string `\host\printer`, because in Python `\` is an escape character, and when you want a single `\` you need to write `\\`.  You can disable this behavior by using a raw string, or by escaping `\` whenever you use it.  So you can write:

```
>>> data = '\\\\host\\printer'
```

Or you can write:

```
>>> data = r'\\host\printer'
```

Since you want the *literal* string `\\\\host\\printer`, you need to replace every instance of `\` with `\\`.  Which means you can write this:

```
>>> newdata = data.replace('\\', '\\\\')
```

And that gets you:

```
>>> print newdata
\\\\host\\printer
```

The [String Literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) section of the docs has some details on the above.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer basically just repeats what I already had in my question details...

Comment: You asked, "I have tried printing it and it certainly does not print the exact value unless I passed in a raw string. What can I do about it?" This attempts to answer that question.  If you're still confused after reading this answer and the linked documentation, I'm curious what else you're missing.  I've explained both the reason that you see the behavior you're asking about as well as the correct way of getting what you want.

Comment: No, that statement was in response to a comment. Read your answer again. It still does not answer my question. In my question, I already stated I KNOW that a raw string will work. The problem is I don't have a raw string to work with.

Comment: The question title clearly says the source is a string variable, not a raw string. Don't downvote my question because you failed to read it properly.

Comment: Please try to keep personal accusations off stackoverflow.  It helps keep it better for everybody. If you don't like the answer, mark it down or whatever but I'm sure we can find a better forum for snarking at eachother. Thanks!

Comment: It boggles my mind really. You have a huge reputation, but can you not clearly see that everything in your answer is already mentioned in my question? Your answer provided absolutely no new information.I only reacted because you blame me for missing things instead.

Comment: I just got 5 downvotes in the past day. I didn't have a single downvote in the previous 2 years. Coincidence? Or revenge?